# Android SQLite errors while inserting records

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have tried many things and searched both SO and google, but this is an odd error. The error happens when I click a button which creates(inserts) a new level in the database.
Logcat follows:

http://pokit.org/get/?564ecab747237335f72006e8e3d5d633.jpg

There is more down but it's the same error.

And here is the code that does the insert. I'm using SQLiteAssetHelper by the way.

```
    public void createLevel(Level lev){


    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    if(lev.getGameMode()=="SinglePlayer")
    {
        LevelSinglePlayer level=(LevelSinglePlayer)lev;
        values.put(GAME_MODE_COLUMN, level.getGameMode());
        values.put(DIFFICULTY_COLUMN, level.getDifficulty());
        values.put(SINGLE_PLAYER_MODE_COLUMN, level.getSinglePlayerMode());
        values.putNull(TIME_CHALLENGE_MODE_COLUMN);
        values.put(POINTS_COLUMN, level.getPoints());
        values.put(LIVES_COLUMN, level.getLives());
        values.putNull(TIME_COLUMN);
        values.put(SUFFIX_COLUMN, level.getSuffix());
        values.put(SUFFIX_WORDS_COUNT_COLUMN, level.getSuffixWordsCount());
        db.insert(LEVELS_TABLE, null, values);
        Log.w("INSERT_NEW_LEVEL", "SUCCESSFUL INSERT");
    }
    else if(lev.getGameMode()=="TimeChallenge")
    {
        LevelTimeChallenge level= (LevelTimeChallenge)lev;
        values.put(GAME_MODE_COLUMN, level.getGameMode());
        values.put(DIFFICULTY_COLUMN, level.getDifficulty());
        values.putNull(SINGLE_PLAYER_MODE_COLUMN);
        values.put(TIME_CHALLENGE_MODE_COLUMN, level.getTimeChallengeMode());
        values.put(POINTS_COLUMN, level.getPoints());
        values.put(LIVES_COLUMN, level.getLives());
        values.put(TIME_COLUMN, level.getTime());
        values.put(SUFFIX_COLUMN, level.getSuffix());
        values.put(SUFFIX_WORDS_COUNT_COLUMN, level.getSuffixWordsCount());
        db.insert(LEVELS_TABLE, null, values);
        Log.w("INSERT_NEW_LEVEL", "SUCCESSFUL INSERT");

    }   
}
```

I have three tables, created by the following statements:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, word TEXT, tezina INTEGER)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS levels(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, modIgre TEXT NOT NULL,  tezina INTEGER NOT NULL, modSingle TEXT, modTime TEXT, targetpoints INTEGER, lives   INTEGER, nastavak TEXT, brojRijeciNastavak INTEGER, locked BOOLEAN, earnedpoints INTEGER, kaladonts INTEGER, req2stars INTEGER, req3stars INTEGER)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS highscores(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, player TEXT, points INTEGER)
```

I can post anything needed quickly.

EDIT: Java consts

```
//konstante(nazivi tabela)
private static final String GAME_MODE_COLUMN = "modIgre";//mod igre - single, time
private static final String DIFFICULTY_COLUMN = "tezina";//tezina rijeci na levelu
private static final String SINGLE_PLAYER_MODE_COLUMN = "modSingle";//mod single playera
private static final String TIME_CHALLENGE_MODE_COLUMN = "modTime";//mod time challenga
private static final String POINTS_COLUMN = "points";
private static final String LIVES_COLUMN = "lives";//zivoti
private static final String TIME_COLUMN = "";//koliko vrijeme?
private static final String SUFFIX_COLUMN = "nastavak";//koji nastavak?
private static final String SUFFIX_WORDS_COUNT_COLUMN = "brojRijeciNastavak";//koliko 
private static final String ID_COLUMN = "_id";
private static final String TARGET_POINTS_COLUMN = "targetpoints";
private static final String LOCKED_COLUMN = "locked";
private static final String KALADONTS_COLUMN = "kaladonts";
private static final String TWO_STARS_COLUMN = "req2stars";
private static final String THREE_STARS_COLUMN = "req3stars";
private static final String EARNED_POINTS_COLUMN = "earnedpoints";
private static final String LEVELS_TABLE = "levels";
```

Comment: there is extra , in ur query

Comment: Where, when I'm using db.insert()?

Comment: yup see in ur log u posted

Comment: But how can I edit it when I'm not doing it manually, sorry I'm new to this

Comment: so where is this query coming from?

Comment: From the db.insert command in the code

Comment: can u post the code that query?

Comment: There is no query just this, this is the code that does the insert.

Comment: m confused how is this query formed fro above code?can u plz explain me so i could help you

Comment: I make a contentvalues instance and pass key value parameters. Then I do a db.insert command which takes the name of the table(LEVELS_TABLE), second value is null, and ContentValues. Then it forms a query.

Comment: One of the keys you're putting to `ContentValues` seems to be an empty string. Also see [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: ohh ok laato is right see ur log posted ur query is mising one filed or ur puting some extra ,

Comment: I'm sorry about all the comments, but I am not clear on wheter or not I should do values.put() for my integer primary key(_id), as it should be autoincremented? Thanks for the string equality.

Comment: You don't need to put a primary key. If it's not specified, a default value will be generated for you. http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: I'm sorry again, but I'm not inserting it yet there is an empty field with that colon. Why should I insert it if it's autoinc?

Comment: To find the column with problems, please post the Java for your `WHATEVER_COLUMN` constants.

Comment: @laalto I have posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TIME_COLUMN` is an empty string, causing the invalid SQL to be created:

```
private static final String TIME_COLUMN = "";//koliko vrijeme?
```

You can replace it with your actual column name. Didn't see a suitable column in your `CREATE TABLE` so it's possible that you should remove the `put(TIME_COLUMN)` calls altogether.

Comment: I have figured it out in the meantime, that was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: I would upvote you a thousand times for that link with differences between equals and ==. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is extra '**,**' in ur query or u r forget to put first field in ur query so correct query is :

```
INSERT into levels(modIgre,modTime,modSingle,brojRijeciNastavak,nastavak,tezina,lives,points)Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary Key seems to be null and values too.

```
INSERT into levels(,modIgre,modTime,modSingle,brojRijeciNastavak,nastavak,tezina,lives,points)Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

it is a problem because you begin your query by ,.